# Java drawing jittering

Tags: java, canvas, draw

I have a thread where i recieve packets with value that goes from 45.0 to 0.0, it's constantly decreasing (it's a timer)

Then I draw a rectangle (length based off this value)
And the rectangle length is jittering (feels like exactly each second)

It's on my phone, but i'll try to make a gif now
Basically it 'jumps' to the previous value which was like half a second before and then comes back to normal

The packets are being sent with 15ms delay between them, i've tried increasing/decreasing the delay, even if i send them with almost 500ms delay its still jittering each second

```
// its this easy, but i dont get where the jittering comes from
if (UdpClientThread.bomb != null) {
    float curExplode = UdpClientThread.bomb.explode;
    canvas.drawRect(0, 0, 24 * curExplode, 200, paintexplode);
}
postInvalidate();
```

here is how i get curExplode

```
...
packet = new DatagramPacket(msg, msg.length);
socket.receive(packet);
String line = new String(packet.getData(), 0, packet.getLength());
if (line.length() > 0 && line.charAt(0) == 'b') {
String[] bomb_data = line.split(Pattern.quote("|"));
if (bomb_data.length == 4) {
    int cur_sq = Integer.parseInt(bomb_data[1]);
    if (cur_sq > prev_sq) {
        bomb = new Bomb(Float.parseFloat(bomb_data[2]), Float.parseFloat(bomb_data[3]));
        prev_sq = cur_sq;
    }
}
...
```

I want it to be smooth :(

EDIT:

video showcasing the problem (it got way worse due to screen recording; ignore the colors its my renderer)

https://youtu.be/tvOYI7Dgu74

EDIT2:

i've added sequence number into UDP packets to verify that its not old value being drawn

this issue still exists

Comment: Hi, could you please [edit] your answer and add a [mcve]? Thanks!

Comment: _It's on my phone_ Does that mean Android?

Comment: yes, it is Android;


sequence numbers in UDP packets didnt fix it apparently, so im sure its not old data being drawn, i have no idea what this could be

Comment: so i've reduced precision and now instead of values like 35.436324 i use 35.4 and it doesnt jitter anymore :\ why is that ? does anyone know ?
if i use 35.43 it will start jittering (i draw the value as a text now as well and i can see those last digits flicker as well)

Comment: The code seems rather innocent and likely unrelated to the problem. Do a `System.out.println("Drawing with "+curExplode)` (or similar log call) under your `drawRect` call and see what it prints.